# Which iPhone English dictionary gives the best pronunciation?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, dictionary

I tried Merriam-Webster and Google Translate, both are far from satisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

I would try the Dictionary.com app.

http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=308750436&mt=8